# SM-T350 Micro-USB port charging but not transmitting files

Tags: adb, samsung, usb

My belief is that my SM-T350 (Samsung Galaxy A 8.0 from 2015) has a corrupted port which can only charge, not transfer files. Is that possible? Has anyone found any fixes short of taking the device apart and replacing the micro-usb port? Have I done anything wrong on the software side (see info below)?

Info:

I recently bought the SM-T350 off ebay as a cheap tablet to install ROMS, root, and generally do things on that I can't do with my daily driver phone. When I went to flash TWRP from my computer (Ubuntu 20.10), I found that the device was not recognized by adb. Specifically, running:

```
adb devices
```

returns the output:

```
List of devices attached
```

implying that no devices are attached, even though the SM-T350 is in the MTP mode in developer settings and USB debugging is enabled.

Seeing this, I figured that I'd run into the age-old problem of a cable which only charges and doesn't transfer data. It had been the cable from the box, so I tried connecting with a different cable (which I know to work both transferring data and charging). `adb devices` still didn't recognize it, so I know something is either wrong with my computer or the tablet at this point.

To eliminate variables, I borrowed my nephew's tablet (coincidentally, a Samsung Galaxy A 8.0 from 2019) and hooked it up (with the working cable, to the same computer) to see if `adb devices` registered anything. Sure enough, it outputted:

```
List of devices attached
R9WMA0N3LCJ device
```

My nephew's tablet (the 2019 one) also was recognized by Ubuntu as a removeable filesystem, whereas no such thing happened for my SM-T350. This is why I believe that the problem lies in the port's file transfer capability.

Comment: did you change your usb cable. Some usb cables are specially made for charging your device that can't help you with FTP.

Comment: I tried to touch on this in the post, but maybe it wasn't clear. I tested the same usb cable with a different device, and file transfer (and adb) worked correctly.

Comment: try switching mtp to ftp if available. still if it don't work it might be a hardware issue.

Comment: have you restarted your computer after installing adb it could be an issue too. because adb installs it's driver to kernel machine requires a reboot to load those drivers. So reboot your computer and try to detect your using `adb devices`.if it still doesn't work try switching mtp to ftp if available. still if it don't work it might be a hardware issue. It too have an SMT-350 1.5 gtwifi tablet which have custom rom installed and working with adb too.

Comment: I installed adb many moons ago, so I don't think rebooting is the issue. I've tried killing and restarting the adb daemon too; no dice. FTP isn't available in the device settings. I'm thinking it's a hardware issue right now as well.

Comment: yes, physical issue is absolutely possible. imagine some dirt on data pins would block any rx/tx but voltage is still available. try to clean with toothbrush and alcohol (nail polish remover). btw he meant PTP (not FTP)

Comment: PTP is available, I think. Will report back later today.

Comment: @alecxs the issue is that one of the data pins has been bent upward out of its slot. Three of the data pins are still in place. Any ideas on how i could bend it back down?

Comment: if you can find such [flex cable](https://www.amazon.com/Charging-Connector-Replacement-Samsung-Galaxy/dp/B00MEC9L2U) with right [board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Galaxy-Tab-A-8-0-2018-Dock-Connector-USB-Charging-Port-Flex-T387-V-T-A-P/252207945014) according to your device model it will be DIY replaceable. otherwise [soldering required](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXJne02zcXs) you should give to professional repair shop

Comment: okay, thanks for your help!